# re/associate a service action with all provision product ids

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-service-catalog

I am working with a service catalog where I need to associate a specific service action with all existing provision artifact IDs using AWS CDK python. The process works fine until a new provision product ID is introduced. Whenever a new provision product ID is added, my current setup attempts to re-associate the service action, which already exists for previous IDs. This results in an error indicating that the service action is already associated with an existing provision product ID. I have to associate all version in code as the AWS::ServiceCatalog::ServiceActionAssociation update requires replacement. so if I associate the latest version, it will disassociate all the previous versions.

I know it is possible via Boto3, but with my current project, it is only possible to use AWS CDK.

How can I modify my approach to ensure the service action is associated with all current and future provision artifact IDs?

Comment: Can you share a code snippet? From what I can tell that resource is for associating a single action with a single artifact, is that not the case?